# Is separating data retrieval code into interfaces and impl. of those interfaces a good idea in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My question is: is the below pattern a good idea in React or no? I come from Java world where this type of code is standard. However, I've ran into several things that, while being a good idea in Java, are NOT a good idea in ReactJS. So I want to make sure that this type of code structure does not have weird memory leaks or hidden side-effects in the react world.

Some notes on below code: I'm only putting everything in the same file for brevity purposes. In real life, the react component the interface and the class would all be in their own source files.

What I'm trying to do: 1) Separate the display logic from data access logic so that my display classes are not married to a specific implementation of talking to a database. 2) Separating DAO stuff into interface + class so that I can later use a different type of database by replacing the class implementaton of the same DAO and won't need to touch much of the rest of the code.

so, A) Is this a good idea in React? B) What sort of things should I watch out for with this type of design? and C) Are there better patterns in React for this that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface Dao {
  getThing: (id: string) => Promise<string>
}

class DaoSpecificImpl implements Dao {
  tableName: string;
  constructor(tableName: string) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
  }
  getThing = async (id: string) => {
    // use a specific database like firebase to
    // get data from tabled called tablename
    return "herp";
  }
}
const dao: Dao = new DaoSpecificImpl("thingies");

const Display: React.FC = () => {
  const [thing, setThing] = useState("derp");

  useEffect(() => {
    dao.getThing("123").then((newThing) => 
    setThing(newThing));
  });

  return (
    <div>{thing}</div>
  )
}
export default Display;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-taussig-g948n?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I would say that this technique is also questionable in Java. In my opinion this is useful only if you expect to have two different implementation at the same time.
Anyway, this question is probably opinion-based and thus offtopic.

Comment: If this causes some sort of memory leak or supernatural behavior (like mutating state does) it would be more than "opinion" based.

Comment: In typescript this won't cause any runtime changes because the types are only a compilation check.

Comment: I'm more concerned with react and the weird stuff that goes on with it in the background. I know a few rules like "don't call hooks inside if statements/ loops./ and random functions, don't mutate state or weird things happen, etc. Just wanna make sure I'm not inadvertently violating that type of no-nos that can mess stuff up in the figure as the app grows.

Comment: IMO this is fine. If you are worried about violating coding rules, you should look into `eslint` with plugins such as `react` and `react-hooks`. Just make sure you don't reimplement a backend on the frontend side. Moreover, react nowadays works with functional components and hooks. You could make a `useDao` hook that returns some method like `getDao` which you can use in your functional component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DaoSpecificImpl approach works however I would change your component to use a React hook:

```
export const useDAO = (initialId = "123") => {
  const [thing, setThing] = useState("derp");
  const [id, setId] = useState(initialId);

  useEffect(() => {
     const fetchThing = async () => {
       try{
         const data = await dao.getThing(id);
         setThing(data);
       }catch(e){
         // Handle errors...
       }
     }
     fetchThing();
  }, [id]);

  return {thing, setId};
}
```

using the hook in your component:

```
const Display = () => {
  const {thing, setId} = useDao("123"); // If you don't specify initialId it'll be "123"

 return <button onClick={() => setId("234")}>{thing}</button> // Pressing the button will update "thing"
}
```

Side note: You could also use a HOC:

```
const withDAO = (WrappedComponent, initialId = "123") => {
 .... data logic... 
  return (props) => <WrappedComponent {...props} thing={thing} setId={setId}/>
};

export default withDAO;
```

E.g. using the HOC to wrap a component:

```
export default withDao(Display); // If you don't specify initialId it'll be "123"
```